# getline() not working on second call

Tags: c++, getline

Could you please look at the following code. The second while loop is not working. If I remove
the first while loop it works fine. What have I done wrong? I am sure it's related to `getline()` but don't know how.

**now the code is updated.
now the vector "line" contains 7 strings, each is a long sentence with comma, i want to parse each elements and store it in 2d vector, the for loop just do this for the first element of line.
for example;
line={"hell,peell,delll,","peer,esdd,rsdd",.....and so on }
now in the first row of vector doom i want {hell, peell, delll} and in the second row 
i want {peer,sedd,rsdd} and so on.
the problem is that the for loop only stores the first element of std::vector line.****

```
   #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<sstream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        ifstream moodle("moodlelist.csv");
        ifstream official("officiallist.csv");
        vector<string> line;
        vector<vector<string>> mood;
        string value1;
        string value2;
        istringstream ss(value1);
        int col=0;
        while ( official.good())   
        {
                getline ( official, value1);
                line.push_back(value1);
        }
     for (int i=0;i<line.size();i++)

{

    value1=line[i];

    cout<<value1<<endl;

    ss.str(value1);

        while(getline(ss,value2, ','))

      {

            row.push_back(value2);

            }

            mood.push_back(row);

            row.clear();

}
        return 0;
    }
```

the code now is updated.
now the vector "line" contains 7 strings, each is a long sentence with comma, i want to parse each elements and store it in 2d vector, the for loop just do this for the first element of line.
for example;
line={"hell,peell,delll,","peer,esdd,rsdd",.....and so on }
now in the first row of vector doom i want {hell, peell, delll} and in the second row 
i want {peer,sedd,rsdd} and so on.
the problem is that the for loop only stores the first element of std::vector line.

Answer (score 2):

After you set the value of `value1`, you need to store that value in `ss`.

```
value1 = "hello,name,apple,sey";
ss.str(value1)
```

Comment: one more thing, i did what you said and it worked but now i want to put the second while loop int a for loop, this only works for the first iteration.

Comment: @user144905 I don't understand... could you rephrase that?

Comment: can you look at my code again, i changed it slightly and described the new problem.

Comment: @user144905 As for the second part of your question, there is nothing wrong with your code, aside from the fact that you're missing a declaration of `std::vector<std::string> row`.